# Check regex pattern multiple times

Tags: javascript, regex

I am writing a regex in javascript to check if a variable name is starting with capital letter.

first example  `var one, two, three;`  this should **not match** and return false because all variables are not starting with capital letter.

first example  `var one, two, Three, four;`  this should **match** and return false because all variables are not starting with capital letter.

I tried this `/var (?![a-z])|var [a-z]+,[A-Z]/`
but it matches only for first and second variables.  But I need it to find until it finds a semicolon because we are not sure how many variables are present in the code.

Comment: Welcome to SO! This could get complicated pretty quickly. What if the `var` list has `foo = "Bar"` as one of the variables (in other words, are you working with initialization as well as declaration)? How about `const`/`let`? Will the source code have string literals that might produce false positives? What about source that relies on automatic semicolon insertion? Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of playing around, I got this: `var ([a-z]+\s*,\s*)*[A-Z][^;]*;`. It basically means:

- `var` : Start with `var`
- `([a-z]+\s*,\s*)*` Skip any `[a-z]+\s*,\s*`, i.e. `abc,` (while ignoring whitespace)
- `[A-Z]` Match a capital letter (as the first letter of a variable)
- `[^;]*;` Match everything until the first `;` you see

Also as a good tip: [RegExr](https://regexr.com/637f8) is a great site to test/design regular expressions:

[image: Screenshot of matches on RegExr]

Comment: Hey! that solves my query but I also need to check if user gives a value to variable.
like var one=1, two=2, Three =3;

Comment: You can add optional groups to the RegExp, e.g. add `(\s*=\s*\d+)?` for "see if you can find `= <number>` but you don't have to". If you allow _any_ JS expression, then RegExp isn't really the right job for this. You'll have to actually parse the JS code to some extent.